# Magento shipping option based on customer group

Tags: shipping-methods, magento2.3.2

Does anyone know how i might be able to modify Magento Shipping module that is in Magento 2.3.2 to allow shipping method based on customer group?

Answer (score 0):

Apply shipping method base on customer group, I think you need to do custom code or use the third-party extension. I would suggest below third party extensions.

https://amasty.com/shipping-payment-by-customer-group-for-magento-2.html
https://marketplace.magento.com/meetanshi-module-payshiprestriction.html
https://www.mageplaza.com/review/shipping-payment-by-customer-groups/

Hope this will help you.

Please let me know if you need further information.

Comment: thanks we are familiar with that plugin. however does it work with the Magento Shipping aka Temando  functionality?

Comment: I think you should send an inquiry(with your requirement) email to them and maybe you got the extension which you needed.